# Python Selenium Dropdown list Clickable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scripting

I want to scrap investing.com website. Firefox Webdriver closes when clicking on one of the dropdown list item.
Dropdown menu is hiidden. I want to choose "BİST Ulusal Tüm" item. What can i do?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://tr.investing.com/equities/turkey"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index-select"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index-select"]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

After you launch the URL and open the application, below pop-up appears, you need to get rid of it first, after that try to perform the other actions.

[image]

**Just add below line:**

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
# Click on I Accept button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
```

Comment: I don't get the popup window but thank you anyway.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? If yes, please share it in your question.

Comment: No error. Just close Firefox Webdrive. Only, Debug last line "WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="index-select"]/div[2]/div/div/div[6]'))).click()". Hoop close Firefox webdrive.